# Do I need "to" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice

> She did what was most sensible: (to) wait.

Do I need the *to*? Why or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the best option is the one that answers the unspoken question in the middle:

> She did what was most sensible.  (What did she do?)  **She waited**.

Other examples:

> While he was waiting for her to come back, he did what any other young, hot-blooded male would do: **he ate** everything he could find in her apartment.
>
> Needing more time, the attorney did the only thing he could think of: **he faked** a medical emergency.

It isn't wrong to just say "wait" after the colon, but in my opinion it's not very good writing style.